# How to display option tag with value and text, through an objects property

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, for-loop, attr

I am trying to create an option tag with an attr of value and use the address from my `startadd` object as its value, and I am trying to assign the text to display for that option as the text property from `startadd` object, but when I input the code I only get (`<option></option>`) on the `console.log` I'm trying to get something like this:

```
<option value="aldama, los angeles, ca">Aldama</option>
```

Here is my code:

```
var startadd = [
 {
   address: "ucla los angeles, ca ",
   text : "UCLA"
 }, 
 {
   address: "aldama elementary los angeles, ca ",
   text : "Aldama"
 },
 {
   address: "franklin high school los angeles, ca",
   text : "Franklin"
 },
];

//loop through topics array to display button in start
function createOptions() {
    //prevent duplicate 
    $("#start").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i <  startadd.length; i++) {
        //new element for option to be created
        var newOption = $('<option>');
        newOption.attr("value", startadd.address);
        newOption.text(startadd.text);
        $("#start").append(newOption);
    }
}
createOptions();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index your array items. At the moment `startadd.address` is not working as `.address` is not a property of an array. It is, however, a property of an object within your array, and so you need to use `startadd[i].address` and `startadd[i].text`.

As a side note, it isn't a good idea to append to the DOM in a loop as appending is an expensive operation, instead, you may consider keeping an array of your elements and then using `.html` to add your array of options to your `<select>` dropdown.

See example below:

```js
var startadd = [{
    address: "ucla los angeles, ca ",
    text: "UCLA"
  },
  {
    address: "aldama elementary los angeles, ca ",
    text: "Aldama"
  },
  {
    address: "franklin high school los angeles, ca",
    text: "Franklin"
  },
];

function createOptions() {
  $("#start").empty();
  var newOptions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < startadd.length; i++) {
    var newOption = $('<option>');
    newOption.attr("value", startadd[i].address); // add [i] here to index element
    newOption.text(startadd[i].text); // add [i] here to index element
    newOptions.push(newOption); // add new option to the array
  }
  $("#start").html(newOptions); // once loop is complete, add the array of elements to the DOM
}
createOptions();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="start"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case , u need to specify the index of arr like that

```
newOption.attr("value", startadd[i].address);
newOption.text(startadd[i].text);
```

but  i advice u should to use map() function or each() to make it easier

```
var startadd = [{address: "ucla los angeles, ca ",
 text : "UCLA"
 }, 
 {address: "aldama elementary los angeles, ca ",
 text : "Aldama"
 },
 {address: "franklin high school los angeles, ca",
 text : "Franklin"
 }];
    //loop through topics array to display button in start
    function createOptions() {
        //prevent duplicate 
        $("#start").empty();
         $(startadd).map((v)=>{
            let newOption = $('<option>');
            newOption.attr("value", v.address);
            newOption.text(v.text);
            $("#start").append(newOption);
         })

    }
    createOptions();
```